# How to add Javascript code using jQuery and setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some tracking code that the provider (WebTraxs) says should be placed at the bottom of the  tag.  The problem is that this same code is causing everything on the page (including my jQuery code) to run AFTER the WebTraxs is executed.  This execution sometimes takes long enough where images rollovers, etc aren't working because the user is mousing over images before WebTraxs has finished.

Therefore, I'm trying to add the needed  tags (from WebTraxs) to the body after the page is loading in the document ready handler, using the following:

```
 setTimeout(function(){

  var daScript = '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/webtraxs.js" />';
  var daOtherScript = '<noscript><img alt="" src="http://db2.webtraxs.com/webtraxs.php?id=company&st=img" />';

  $('body').append(daScript);
  $('body').append(daOtherScript);

 },  
 5000);
```

I have two problems with the above:

1. In Firefox, after 5 seconds, it page goes completely blank.
2. In IE, there's no errors thrown, but normally you can see the WebTraxs code trying to load a tracking image in the status bar.  This is not occurring with the above code.

Is there a better way to accomplish my objective here?  I'm basically just trying to make sure the WebTraxs code is executed AFTER the document ready handler is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use jQuery's DOMReady event handler. The reason people use DOMReady is that it allows the full DOM to load before firing up scripts that manipulate the page. If you call your scripts too early, parts of your page may not be accessible -- for example, if you call them before `<div id="footer">...</div>`, they won't be able to see `$('div#footer')` because it's not been pulled into the DOM yet. And that's great, except that your DOMReady methods will always execute **after** any in-page scripts have executed first. That's why your webtrax code is getting executed first.

But you can get the same benefits of DOMReady and still control the order of execution by calling your page scripts at the end of your document, when there's nothing left but HTML closing tags. They will be executed in the order they appear.

So try this instead:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myPageScripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pagesection1"></div>
    <div id="pagesection2"></div>
    <div id="pagesection3"></div>
    <!--NO MORE CONTENT BELOW THIS LINE-->
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        runMyPageInitializerScripts();
    //]]></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/webtraxs.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this script, `runMyPageInitializerScripts()` would still have complete access to `#pagesection1`, `pagesection2` and `pagesection3`, but would not see the final `script` tag. So the page isn't in **exactly** the same condition as when DOMReady is fired, but for most scripts usually there is no downside.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the [`.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function:

```
 setTimeout(function(){

  $.getScript("http://path.to/Scripts/webtraxs.js");
 },  
 5000);
```

What it's really curious about your code is that you add a `<noscript>` tag using JavaScript... it does not make any sense. If the user does not have JavaScript the `setTimeout` won't be fired, thus it `<noscript>` content won't be displayed.

> I'm basically just trying to make sure the  WebTraxs code is executed AFTER the document ready handler is executed.

In that case, you just have to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript("http://path.to/Scripts/webtraxs.js");
});
```

Comment: If OP is already using jQuery, this must be the right answer. The OP's approach is reinvention of a working API already at their disposal.

Comment: The noscript can safely be written directly into the document rather than dynamically... and pointlessly :)

Comment: Ok - I just tried .getScript, but in FF, it still just makes a blank page after 5 seconds.  I've eliminated the noscript tag.

Comment: I don't know why, but $.getScript isn't really working for me on this one in FF.  It probably has something to do with the script it's calling.

Answer (score 2):

`<script>` tags cannot use a shortcut like `<script/>`.

You **have** to use  `<script></script>`

Anyways, I don't understand where the difference is on executing those scripts on `DOMready` or after a specific amount of time. If it blocks the UI it will do the same after 5 seconds no?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the closing `</script>` and `</noscript>` tags.

Comment: `<script>` is not a self-closing tag, but jQuery knows enough to ignore this error and call the script as if there were a closing tag. Putting `<noscript>` into a script at all is completely useless: if the user has JS enabled, it will get inserted into the document and ignored, and if the user has JS disabled, nothing will get written at all. I'm sort of amazed at the number of people I see doing this.

Comment: @Andrew - point taken on the `<noscript>` tag inserted by JavaScript. However, outputting well formatted HTML is always best practice, regardless of what JS or Frameworks can handle on your behalf.

Comment: I guess you're right, certainly on a site where lots of people come to learn good technique and could come away with bad habits instead. jQuery tends to mangle good style with their use "symbolic" HTML tags; stuff like `$('<img>').attr('width',200).attr('height',100).attr('alt','An image')`. It makes sense because when you create elements with `document.createElement()` you don't have to create closing tags either. But making it look like good HTML does no harm and might do others some good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `<script>` tag you may need to escape it (not sure if this persists on newest browsers, but as far as i remember you can't have `<script>` tags inside a script tag), take old google analytics code as example:

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

Splitting the script tag also works:

```
document.write("<scr"+"ipt src='somescript.js'></sc"+"ript>");
```

But since you're using jQuery, `.getScript()` is your best option.